# Cannot include module in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using

```
Ruby version              1.8.7
Rails version             3.0.3
```

I have a method called alive in every model of my rails app:

```
  def alive
    where('deleter is null')  
  end
```

I don't want to copy this code in every model so I made a /lib/life_control.rb

```
module LifeControl    
  def alive
    where('deleter is null')  
  end   

  def dead
    where('deleter is not null')  
  end    
end
```

and in my model (for example client.rb) I wrote:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  include LifeControl   
end
```

and in my config/enviroment.rb I wrote this line:

```
require 'lib/life_control'
```

but now I get a no method error:

```
NoMethodError in
ClientsController#index

undefined method `alive' for
#<Class:0x10339e938>

app/controllers/clients_controller.rb:10:in
`index'
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you calling the method at the class or instance level?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`include` will treat those methods as instance methods, not class methods. What you want to do is this:

```
module LifeControl    
  module ClassMethods
    def alive
      where('deleter is null')  
    end   

    def dead
      where('deleter is not null')  
    end    
  end

  def self.included(receiver)
    receiver.extend ClassMethods
  end
end
```

This way, `alive` and `dead` will be available on the class itself, not instances thereof.

Comment: I was searching furiously but found no good answer until I got your response. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you extend instead of include your module methods will be assigned to the class.

Answer (score 12):

I'm aware this is a pretty old question, the accepted answer did work for me, but that meant me having to re-write a lot of code because i have to change the module to a nested one.

This is what helped me with my situation and should work with most of today's applications.(not sure if it'll work in the ruby/rails version in the question)

instead of doing `include` use `extend`

So as per the question, the sample code would look like:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend LifeControl   
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put this line in application.rb file

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Edited:

This line is working fine for me.
I want to suggest one more thing, ruby 1.8.x is not compatible with rails 3.x.
So just update your ruby for version 1.9.2

Following is my POC

```
In lib folder:
lib/test_lib.rb

module TestLib
 def print_sm
   puts "Hello World in Lib Directory"
 end
end


In model file:

include TestLib
def test_method
  print_sm
end

And In application.rb

config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]


Now you can call test_method like this in controller:

ModelName.new.test_method #####Hello World in Lib Directory
```

Comment: Did you restart your application?

Comment: After adding specified line r u still getting the same error??

Comment: yes, i get the error when i write Client.alive in my ClientsController.rb i want to import the methods from my modul in all my models

Comment: He said he added "require 'lib/life_control'" and the autoload does nothing else, so that can't be the solution. Unless that "require" fails, which is not reported.